# JestJs thinks ajax is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, jestjs

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a simple jest test to work. Jest insists that my Ajax call is not happening, with the error message:

```
FAIL  authTest.js (1.828s)
● Authentication: Logging In › it Doesn't currently have a logged in user
  - Expected Function to be called with { url : 'api/loggedin', type : 'GET', error :       <jasmine.any(function Function() { [native code] })>, success : <jasmine.any(function Function() { [native code] })> }.
    at Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/ritmatter/reps/spec/authTest.js:13:20)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

The code being tested is in a file called auth.jsx, and it looks like this:

```
loggedIn: function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'api/loggedin',
    type: 'GET',
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      return false;
    }.bind(this),
    success: function(data) {
      return true;
    }.bind(this),
  });
},
```

The test looks like this:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
"use strict";
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('Authentication: Logging In', function() {
  it('Doesn\'t currently have a logged in user', function () {
    var $ = require('jquery');
    jest.dontMock('../js/auth.jsx');
    var auth = require('../js/auth.jsx');
    auth.loggedIn();
    expect($.ajax).toBeCalledWith({
      url: 'api/loggedin',
      type: 'GET',
      error: jasmine.any(Function),
      success: jasmine.any(Function)
    });
  });
});
```

Any idea why jest would think that this is not getting called? I've been looking around, and it seems like there are some bugs with respect to dontMock() and mock().

Comment: You can't call react component methods from outside the react component, unless they are in the `statics: {}` object.  Static methods don't get access to an instance of the component though.

Comment: Auth is a plain javascript object, not a react component, so I don't think that should be an issue. The file closely models the tutorial here: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial.html#content, except that auth is a .jsx file and not a .js file.

Comment: Yeah it being a .jsx file is confusing because why would a non-react component class method be in a .jsx instead of .js?

Answer (score 1):

As Wagner mentioned, you need to require jquery globally, outside of your test.  Your component is using the global version of $, so adding `var $ = require('jquery')` doesn't do anything in terms of adding jquery to the global variable $.

You also did not mock the ajax call.

When testing react, I avoid issues with loading jquery by simply redefining $:

```
window.$ = {ajax: jest.genMockFunction()}
```

So, as long as you don't need jquery for anything else other than an ajax call, this one line will simulate the jquery root and mock the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a React component that invoked ajax on initialisation.
What I found is that `expect` on `$` only work if you require `jquery` outside the `it` method.

My React component and test case are like these (They are ES6 but you can get the idea)

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {things:[]};
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/things',
      success: (result) => this.setState(result),
      error: (ex) => console.log(ex)
    })
  }

  render() {
    //stuff
  }
}
```

and the test

```
jest.dontMock('../components/MyComponent')

import React from 'react'
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import $ from 'jquery'

const Wall = require('../components/MyComponent');

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  it('calls the things end point', () => {
    const myComp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent />)

    expect($.ajax).toBeCalledWith({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/things',
      success: jasmine.any(Function),
      error: jasmine.any(Function)
    })
  });
});
```